Will the ROS2 node be automatically reclaimed?
def main():
    rclpy.init() 
    pub_demo = Topic_Pub("publisher_node") 
    rclpy.spin(pub_demo)     
    pub_demo.destroy_node()  
    rclpy.shutdown()  

If the destroy_node() function is not used, will executing rclpy.shutdown() reclaim and destroy the related nodes?
I'm not quite sure how to monitor whether a node has been destroyed.If possible, please also let me know how to monitor whether a node has been destroyed, Thanks.
